# htaccess rewrite path keeping the old path on the browser

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site with a few pages.

I want to get all this paths:

```
/events/first
/events/second/edit/
/events/whatever/foo/bar
```

Redirected to `/show_event`, but I want to keep the original url (`/events/second/edit`) on the browser, because I use a `react` script on the frontend that needs to read from it.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !wc-api [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# BEGIN iThemes Security
....

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

** MY CODE HERE **

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^events/.*$ https://example.com/show_event [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^events/.*$ ?pagename=show_event [NC,L]
```

These two gets the redirect done, but in the url appears `/show_event`, so I can't use it

```
RewriteRule ^events/.*$ show_event [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^events/.*$ /show_event [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^events/.*$ ^show_event [NC,L]
```

None of this three rules works, I just get a wordpress page not found error page

Any ideas?

Comment: For WP rewrites you must use WP rewrite API instead of .htaccess rules.

Comment: I started doing that, using WP `add_rewrite_rule`, but it was just editing the htaccess exactly the same way, and I was getting the same results as I stated on the OP, so I decided to try it with htaccess directly